# Solve optimal weights by maximizing sharpe ratio with PortfolioAnalytics package in R

Tags: r, r-portfolioanalytics

I'm running [this demo](https://github.com/R-Finance/PortfolioAnalytics/blob/master/demo/demo_max_Sharpe.R) and have a question on the following code:

```
'library(PortfolioAnalytics)

data(edhec)
R <- edhec[, 1:8]
funds <- colnames(R)

init.portf <- portfolio.spec(assets=funds)
init.portf <- add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf, type="full_investment")
init.portf <- add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf, type="long_only")
init.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init.portf, type="return", name="mean")
init.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init.portf, type="risk", name="StdDev")
init.portf

maxSR.lo.ROI <- optimize.portfolio(R=R, portfolio=init.portf, 
                                   optimize_method="ROI", 
                                   maxSR=TRUE, trace=TRUE)
maxSR.lo.ROI'
```

When I run the demo, I find that it only works when the data is cut like `R <- edhec[, 1:8]`. If I want to use `R <- edhec[, 1:13]` , the optimal weights are NA and I get the following warning:

> In optimize(f = sharpe_obj_fun, R = R, constraints = constraints,  ... :
>   NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value

What is the reason for this problem?

Comment: Something wrong with your environment. The example runs fine... Objective Measure: StdDev: 0.009021, mean: 0.0062